# Does git rebase allow you to squash onto a different non-parent commit?

Tags: git, git-rebase

currently, `git rebase -i` shows

```
pick aa89fe9 getdicts: url fixes, and quotes in shell scripting.
pick b3d1e34 fixed silly-long title, and block-code quoting (4-spaces)
pick 8cfb562 oops
```

I want to squash `8cfb562` onto/and `aa89fe9` and leave `b3d1e34` as-is. Does `git rebase` allow me to do this, if not -- what's the most efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean by "squash"? Squashing is converting multiple commits into a single commit for clarity; you can't really squash a single commit.

Comment: I want to squash 8cfb562 onto/and aa89fe9 and leave b3d1e34 as-is.

Comment: Yep I see that. I was confused by the word "squash" since that's not the word that describes that operation. You might prefer "move" or "rebase".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to squash `8cfb562` onto `aa89fe9` and leave `b3d1e34` as-is. Does `git rebase` allow me to do this ...

Yes: simply re-arrange the instructions into the desired order, as the docs instruct

> # These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.

So it looks like this

```
pick aa89fe9 getdicts: url fixes, and quotes in shell scripting.
pick 8cfb562 oops
pick b3d1e34 fixed silly-long title, and block-code quoting (4-spaces)
```

and then replace the second `pick` with `squash` or `s`.

Note that it's likely you will have to resolve some sort of conflicts if one of the "moved" commits depends on one of the used-to-be-earlier, now-actually-later operations.